# MVC - Update details with UserID in HiddenFor - is this secure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, post, forms-authentication

I have a website whereby a user can log in and then update their details.
The forms fields are title, name, address etc. and I have a HiddenFor where I put the UserID.

When the form is posted, it uses the UserID to know which user's details to update.

Looking at the POST with Fiddler I can see the hidden field and its data being sent. I am of course concerned that I could craft a POST with this, changing the UserID to another value and updating somebody else's data.

Does the AntiForgeryToken in the front & ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute in the back resolve this completely? Or is there another step?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
```

Comment: don't you check in controller, witch user sent this request and compare it with userId that comes with form? I mean server side validation.

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085019/secure-way-to-delete-a-record-in-asp-net-mvc